# Passing a LINQ query value to a view layout shared across many view screens

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using a sharedLayout page that is across all my asp.net pages and I want a "Hello FirstName LastName" of the user logged in at the top of each view. To get this I am querying my database and returning a linq object. How do I pass this object to the view as it is a sharedlayout across all my view pages like this.

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Begin";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/sharedLayout.cshtml";
}
```

That is at the top of each of my view pages and in my sharedLayout page I have the follow part to display the user first/lastname

```
<div class="nav-bar">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><img src="~/Images/logo.png" id="logo" /></a>
            <img src="~/Images/testpicture.png" id="userpic" />
            <span id="user">I want the first name/lastname here from a linq object</span>
        </div>
```

I know how to pass it to a view from the controller `return View(linqobjecthere)` but since this view is shared, how can I pass it to the layout view rather than the currently displaying view.

Comment: You can create a Base Controller and define your ViewBag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use @Html.RenderAction()

Set up a controller action that returns the data you need:

```
// ChildActionOnly attribute makes sure that
// the action cannot be called directly from the url
[ChildActionOnly] 
public ActionResult UserInfo() {
    // Get the data you need
    var userInfo = (Linq to get userInfo);

    return PartialView("UserInfo", userInfo);
}
```

Then create a strongly typed partial view called "UserInfo" with your view html:

```
@model UserInfo

<div class="nav-bar">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
        <img src="~/Images/logo.png" id="logo" />
    </a>
    <img src="@Model.UserPicHref" id="userpic" />
    <span id="user">@Model.FirstName @Model.LastName</span>
</div>
```

In the shared layout, call `@{Html.RenderAction("UserInfo", "ControllerName")}`

Note that `RenderAction()` needs to be called within `@{ }`.  There is also an `Html.Action()` that does not have this requirement.  From what I've heard `RenderAction` is faster because it writes directly to the `Response`

Comment: Thank you for the help, perfect :)